# Typescript type guard not inferred string literal

Tags: typescript, typeguards, inferred-type

I try to understand is such behavior a bug?
I defined `guard(a: T|undefined)` and passed to it value of type `"admin"|undefined` which is obviously subtype of `string|undefined`. But guard did not removed `|undefined` after filtering.

It is tricky for me, because if I change `if (user === 'Jack') return 'admin'` to `if (user === 'Jack') return 'admin' as string;` then type guard works correctly, `string|undefined` becomes `string`.

```js
function getPermissions(user: string){
    if (user === 'Jack') return 'admin';
    return undefined;
}
const admins = ['Mike', 'Joe'].map(e => getPermissions(e)); //type ("admin"|undefined)[]

function isDefined<T>(a: T | undefined): a is T {
    return a !== undefined;
}

const foundAdmins = admins.filter(isDefined); //type is ("admin"|undefined)[] but string[] expected
```

You could run it in a playground [typescrypt playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQAqoE4FsYDOB8YBAFCATgFyIFTYxjICUA3gLABQiviMwRBSrZEAXgmIA5ACkAhhADWUlomzoQ2JFLkATfGCkBubnzUaticLtTAmqXSa4BfbhAT1EegwXGIA2lIAsjCKqFIANNIycOEAugB0uHIADmSo4gB8KOhYeITEHuksLEaIAPTlUACeKRlkAETeTA0APta29ros-nHc3KCQsAj8BAAinWAOADwAKplkcrSziK1WYDZ2U920cqOIK5w8fOpQmkh7AISSHVsOTq5cbh5QiMBw1gCC+ky+Yl4-UgJOwAGygODIhAmd26ZUqNTq+0azTAbVuXR6fR4-S4QA)

Comment: Hmm, this does look like a TS bug or at least an inference limitation.  There are various workarounds like [these](https://tsplay.dev/Na4p9w).  Are you more interested in finding out whether this is a bug (in which case I need to look at github issues or file one) or how to work around it (in which case I can write up the code linked above as an answer)?

Comment: I am interested in understanding such behaviour of compiler, whether it is a bug or not.

Comment: Well, I haven't found a relevant github issue yet... someone might want to file one. (or find one)

Comment: Super interesting!  If I set a return type of `'admin' | undefined` on the `getPermissions` function then the filtering works as expected and we get `"admin"[]`.  It is only a problem when the `'admin' | undefined` return type is inferred.  That definitely feels like a bug and I cannot explain it.

Comment: `admins.filter(isDefined<"admin">);` works too - the compiler doesn't understand that you expect `undefined` to be _outside_ `T`.

Comment: I opened a github issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51980

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with generic widenind `"admin"` to `string`

You can make that work *the same way*, buuuuuut with `typescript@^5`

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.0-dev.20221220#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQAqoE4FsYDOB8YBAFCATgFyIFTYxjICUA3gLABQiviMwRBSrZEAXgmIA5ACkAhhADWUlomzoQ2JFLkATfGCkBubnzUaticLtTAmqXSa4BfbhAT1EegwXGIA2lIAsjCKqFIANNIycOEAugB0uHIADmSo4gB8KOhYeITEHuksLEaIAPTlUACeKRlkAETeTA0APta29ros-nHc3KCQsAj8BAAinWAOADwAKplkcrSziK1WYDZ2U920cqOIK5w8fOpQmkh7AISSHVsOTq5cbh5QiMBw1gCC%20ky%20Yl4-UgJOwAGygODIhAmd26ZW4lTMAD0APzw8qIdykV7vL6Agi0RrNMANVbrTZdHp9J5cQbQEijaFdADqMCgAAsAMIvaaYzzzRbLUm3Cm7faHUwnCwXRDXf7C7YPfpcXnYj4bb4%20ABMfiJBGBMDBEKhkwcLPZXKxpUQaKRqK4CJVbzVug1v01tCagIavW4QA)

```
function getPermissions(user: string){
    if (user === 'Jack') return 'admin';
    return undefined;
}
const admins = ['Mike', 'Joe'].map(e => getPermissions(e)); //type ("admin"|undefined)[]

function isDefined<T>(a: T | undefined): a is T {
    return a !== undefined;
}

const foundAdmins = admins.filter(isDefined); 
//    ^?
// const foundAdmins: ("admin" | undefined)[]

function isDefinedWithConst<const T>(a: T | undefined): a is T {
    return a !== undefined;
}

const foundAdmins2 = admins.filter(isDefinedWithConst); 
//    ^?
// const foundAdmins2: "admin"[]
```

```
// dirty but works
const foundAdmins3 = admins.filter((e): e is 'admin' => isDefined<'admin'>(e)); 
//    ^?
// const foundAdmins3: "admin"[]
```

or make an overload for that specific case

```
function nonNullable<T>(v: T | null | undefined): v is T { return v != null }
interface Array<T> {
    filter(p: typeof nonNullable): NonNullable<T>[]
}
const foundAdmins4 = admins.filter(nonNullable);
//    ^?
// const foundAdmins4: "admin"[]
```